# expect script fails to send passphrase to cryptsetup

Tags: linux, expect

a simple interaction with cryptsetup that I want to automate is this:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop20
WARNING: Device /dev/loop20 already contains a 'crypto_LUKS' superblock signature.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/loop20 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
Enter passphrase for /dev/loop20: 
Verify passphrase:
```

The following expect script tries to do this:

```
spawn cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop20
expect "yes): " { send "YES\n" }
expect ": " 
send "passphrase\n"
expect ": "  
send "passphrase\n"
expect eof
```

While the YES gets properly sent, it hangs at the passphrase prompt. I also tried to use \r in addition to \n in the send command.

The same script structure works fine for ssh password or sudo password prompts, so I'm a bit lost what is different here. I know there are "expect-less" methods, e.g., echo passphrase | cryptsetup ..., but I really would like to understand the underlying problem and whether there is a solution to this.

Comment: Run the script with `expect -d` and see if the patterns are matching.

Comment: You often need to insert a wait (eg `sleep 1`) after matching a password prompt to allow for the tty being set to no-echo mode with an associated input flush.

Answer (score 1):

meuh's comment is the solution: I need to wait a little after the password prompt.

So this works:

```
spawn cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop20
expect "yes): " { send "YES\n" }
expect ": " 
sleep 1
send "passphrase\n"
expect ": "  
sleep 1
send "passphrase\n"
expect eof
```

Thank you!